# Can't catch an exception

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

This is the full code: TomTimers::set() will throw an exception, but the try/catch block in tom_timing_test.cpp doesn't seem to catch it.  When I run it, I get this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'TomTimers_Exception'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

tom_timing_test.h

```
#ifndef TOM_TIMING_TEST_H
#define  TOM_TIMING_TEST_H

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <utility>

typedef struct timespec timespec_t;

#define ORWL_NANO (+1.0E-9)
#define ORWL_GIGA UINT64_C(1000000000)

// =============================================================================
#ifdef __MACH__ // support for OS X
// =============================================================================

#include <mach/clock.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>

// timebase is a scaling factor that converts the difference between
// two mach_absolute_times into seconds.
static double   orwl_timebase = 0.0;
static uint64_t orwl_timestart = 0;

timespec_t porta_gettime(void) {
    if (!orwl_timebase) {
    mach_timebase_info_data_t tb;
    mach_timebase_info(&tb);
    orwl_timebase = tb.numer;
    orwl_timebase /= tb.denom;
    orwl_timestart = mach_absolute_time();
    }
    timespec_t t;
    double diff = (mach_absolute_time() - orwl_timestart) * orwl_timebase;
    t.tv_sec = diff * ORWL_NANO;
    t.tv_nsec = diff - (t.tv_sec * ORWL_GIGA);
    return t;
}

// =============================================================================
#else   // support for Linux
// =============================================================================

// porta_gettime() - Get real time as a timespec_t
// timespec{sec, nsec}
timespec_t porta_gettime(void) {
    timespec_t tnow;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tnow);
    return tnow;
}

#endif
// =============================================================================


#include <string>
#include "wd_sprintf.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

using std::set;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using boost::unordered_map;


typedef struct  {
    double avg_onset;
    double avg_duration;
    long   samples;
} Average;

typedef unordered_map<string, Average>      Average_Map;
typedef unordered_map<string, timespec_t>   Timer_Map;

static timespec_t  t0;       // absolute timebase
static const Average init_avg {0,0,0};

class TomTimers_Exception : std::runtime_error {
public:
    TomTimers_Exception(string const& msg) : std::runtime_error(msg) {}
};

class TomTimers {
public:
    TomTimers() {
    t0 = porta_gettime(); // set an absolute timebase
    }

    void set() {
        if ( !_timer_map.empty() ) {
            // There are still running timers.  Usage error.
            throw TomTimers_Exception("TomTimers::set() called with active timers.");
        }
        _cycle = porta_gettime(); // set the start-of-cycle time
    }

    void start(const string& id) {
    timespec_t now = porta_gettime(); // get real time
    start(id, now);
    }
    void start(const string& id, timespec_t time) {
    _timer_map[id] = time;
    _average_map.insert(std::make_pair(id, init_avg));
    }

    timespec_t stop(const string& id) {
        timespec_t ts_start = _timer_map[id];
        timespec_t ts_stop  = porta_gettime();
        Average    previous = _average_map[id];
        timespec_t tdur;

        // Compute this duration and update avg duration
        tdur.tv_sec  = ts_stop.tv_sec - ts_start.tv_sec; // can't be neg
        tdur.tv_nsec = ts_stop.tv_nsec - ts_start.tv_nsec; // might be neg
    double new_duration = tdur.tv_sec * ORWL_GIGA + tdur.tv_nsec;
    _average_map[id].avg_duration =
        (previous.avg_duration * previous.samples + new_duration)
        / (_average_map[id].samples + 1);

    // Compute this onset and update avg onset
        tdur.tv_sec  = ts_start.tv_sec - _cycle.tv_sec; // can't be neg
        tdur.tv_nsec = ts_start.tv_nsec - _cycle.tv_nsec; // might be neg
    double new_onset = tdur.tv_sec * ORWL_GIGA + tdur.tv_nsec;
    _average_map[id].avg_onset =
        (previous.avg_onset * previous.samples + new_onset)
        / (_average_map[id].samples + 1);

    ++(_average_map[id].samples);

        _timer_map.erase(id);
    return ts_stop;
    }

    // stop_start(id1, id2)
    //
    // Stops id1's timer and starts id2's timer at the same time.
    void stop_start(const string& id_stop, const string& id_start) {
        start(id_start, stop(id_stop));
    }

    void dump() {
    // Sort the names by copying them into an ordered set
    // and why the FUCK do I have to say std:: ???
    std::set<string> ordered_set;
    BOOST_FOREACH( Average_Map::value_type& i, _average_map) {
        ordered_set.insert(i.first);
    }

        BOOST_FOREACH(const std::set<string>::value_type& v, ordered_set) {
            cout << wd_sprintf("%s: Onset %12.8f Dur %12.8f [%d samples]",
                   v,
                   _average_map[v].avg_onset,
                   _average_map[v].avg_duration,
                   _average_map[v].samples)
         << endl;
        }
    }

private:

    timespec_t  _cycle;
    Timer_Map   _timer_map;
    Average_Map _average_map;

};


#endif
```

tom_timing_test.cpp

```
#include "tom_timing_test.h"

int
main( int argc, char** argv) {

    long repetitions;
    if (argc > 1) {
        repetitions = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    else {
        cout << "You need repetitions" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    TomTimers tt;

    const string DUR_1 {"Phase 1"};
    const string DUR_2 {"Phase 2"};
    const string DUR_3 {"Phase 3"};

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i) {
            tt.set();
            tt.start(DUR_1);
            //        sleep(1);
            tt.stop_start(DUR_1, DUR_2);
            //        sleep(2);
            tt.stop_start(DUR_2, DUR_3);
            //        sleep(2);        
            //  tt.stop(DUR_3);
        }

        tt.dump();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        cout << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well u now, when you catch as `exception` then the thrown class must either be `exception` or have `exception` as an **accessible** (which in this case means `public`) base class.

Comment: Mercy! I plumb forgot.  Thank 'ee!

Comment: some chap edited the language (lack of understanding), and for good measure edited the technical content as well (lack of understanding) so that the answer became incorrect and meaningless. and this was approved by 4 others. i just rolled back the edits now, but please folks, **don't favor looks over correctness**, don't approve edits that make answers incorrect, no matter how seductive & attractive the new speling-corect vording mey seam.

Comment: @Chap: Oh! I didn't notice your nick. Sorry! He he, what a coincidence. :)